# Limit JPA Specification query to fetch required data

Tags: java, jpa, specifications

I've 3 tables:

```
School
    school_id, school_name, student_id
Student
    student_id, student_name ,subject_id
Subject
    subject_id, subject_name
```

There is one to many relation between School -> Student -> Subject, and I've created entities in that relation only.

I'm writing `specification` query to fetch students of a particular school:

```
List<Student> students = schoolRepo.findAll(Specification.where (findStudents(schoolId));
```

---

```
public static Specification<Student> findStudents(long schoolId) {
    return (root, query, cbuilder) -> {
        root.fetch("students", JoinType.LEFT);
        return cbuilder.and(cbuilder.equal(root.get("school"), schoolId));
    };
}
```

Although I'm not fetching subjects anywhere in the specifications query or in code (like using `get`).

I can still see in logs in generated queries that subjects are getting fetched eventually.

How can I update my query to limit to only school & student?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use EntityGraph instead. It helps improve the performance of loading entities. You can do it like this

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph (
  name="school-students",
  attributeNodes = {
     @NamedAttributeNode("students")
  }
)
public class School implements Serializable { ... }


And then in your repository use it like this : 

@Override
@EntityGraph(value = "school-students",
     type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
@Query( value = "SELECT s FROM School s where s.id =:id")
School findOne();
```